# How to get an already issued SAML assertion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml-2.0, thinktecture

I have a scenario where I have an ASP.Net application that authenticates using the Thinktecture IdentityServer. This all works fine, it has a relationship with our ADFS and that is all working great. What I need though is to call the ShareFile-NET SDK and authenticate using the below sample code..

```
    //SAML Authentication: This authentication support assumes you have a mechanism for obtaining a SAML assertion, samlAssertion from the user's IdP.

var sfClient = new ShareFileClient("https://secure.sf-api.com/sf/v3/");
var oauthService = new OAuthService(sfClient, "[clientid]", "[clientSecret]");

var oauthToken = await oauthService.ExchangeSamlAssertionAsync(samlAssertion,
  subdomain, applicationControlPlane);

sfClient.AddOAuthCredentials(oauthToken);
sfClient.BaseUri = oauthToken.GetUri();
```

So I have the IdP, but I have not had any luck researching how exactly to make use of the token it has provided me to create that "samlAssertion" parameter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this.

The SAML assertion can be found in the ClaimsIdentity

```
var icp = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current;

        var claimsIdentity = icp.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

        var token = claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;
```

For this to be populated you need to add the following to the web.config:

```
<identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
```